# How to change of the packingslip pdf file name (Shipment) with the shipping ID generated from admin?

Tags: magento2, magento-community, pdf, magento2.4.4, issue

Use di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\PrintAction" type="Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\PrintAction" />
</config>
```

Use PrintAction.php

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\PrintAction
{

    public function execute()
    {
       
        $shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');
        if ($shipmentId) {
            $shipment = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::class)->load($shipmentId);
            if ($shipment) {
                $pdf = $this->_objectManager->create(
                    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment::class
                )->getPdf(
                    [$shipment]
                );
                $date = $this->_objectManager->get(
                    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class
                )->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
                $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

                return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                    'packingslip' . $shipmentId . '.pdf',
                    $fileContent,
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
            }
        } else {
            /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward $resultForward */
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            return $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        }
    }
}
```

But i am unable to any changes.

Is it possible to change the filename of the Shiping PDF-files in Magento 2 to a format like "packingslip_100123.pdf"? We have tried with the lot of solution given by many developer's solution but we aren't able to change? I am using magento 2.4.4 version. Please help anyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can't override the abstract class using preference, so we can achieve this by plugin
app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml;

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\PrintAction">
        <plugin name="test_printaction_plugin" type="Development\Test\Plugin\PrintAction" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin file:
app/code/Development/Test/PrintAction.php

```
<?php

namespace Development\Test\Plugin;

use Closure;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward;
use Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment;

class PrintAction
{
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    public function __construct(
        FileFactory                                       $fileFactory,
        ObjectManagerInterface         $objectManager,
        ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
    )
    {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\PrintAction $subject, Closure $proceed)
    {
        $shipmentId = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');

        if ($shipmentId) {
            $shipment = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment::class)->load($shipmentId);

            if ($shipment) {
                $pdf = $this->objectManager->create(
                    Shipment::class
                )->getPdf(
                    [$shipment]
                );

// Replace date with shipmentId in the filename
                $filename = 'packingslip' . $shipmentId . '.pdf';

                $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

                return $this->fileFactory->create(
                    $filename,
                    $fileContent,
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
            }
        } else {
            /** @var Forward $resultForward */
            $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
            return $resultForward->forward('noroute');
        }

// If the above conditions are not met, proceed with the original execution
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```